# django queryset between two tables without foreign key

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to fetch results from two tables which does n't have a foreign key relation, Just want to know approach I'm using is right or not.

```
django.db import models
django.contrib.auth.user import User

class UserWorkExperience(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    salary = models.IntegerField(null=True,default='0')

class UserSkills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So What I want is all records for

1. skills of all user which have job-title 'software engineer' and salary greater than '100000'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user_ids = UserWorkExperience.objects.filter(job_title='software engineer', salary__gt=100000).values_list('user', flat=True)
skills = UserSkills.objects.filter(user__in=user_ids)
```

It is recommended to use a `ForeignKey` for job_title and also `skill_name`